# Under what circumstances will the ctl00 prefix render as something else ex. ctl01?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, naming

I've inherited an application that contains a ton of javascript with hardcoded client ids.

In the past when I did load testing I seem to remember that sometimes the generated client ID would start with ctl01.

Under what circumstances will this occur?

Comment: Good question.  Most of the time out client ID's are rendering as ctl01, but on one server it renders ctl00.  Please post the answer if you find it

Comment: have you got the expected answer ?

Comment: @ParagMeshram Unfortunately no. You've have the relevant information from the article that explains how `ctl00` is rendered however my question is more related to an already deployed application where, for reasons currently unknown, the MasterPage's id will render to the client as `ctl00` for one request and `ctl01` for another request. Much like the issue Mr Smith has where for some reason one server returns a ids prefixed with `ctl00` and another server returns ids prefixed with `ctl01`.

Answer (score 9):

First of all 'ctlxx' is prefix of control's master page.

[image]

The ASP.NET engine sets the ID values at runtime for those controls whose IDs have not been explicitly set. It uses the naming pattern ctlXX, where XX is a sequentially increasing integer value. So, in case of nested master pages you will get prefix as `ctlxx` where `xx` will be incremented value.

Control's `Id` value is prefixed with the master page's ID value, `ctl00`. The net effect is an id attribute value consisting of the `ID values of the master page`, the ContentPlaceHolder control, and the Control itself.

**Conclusion -**

So, only case when `ctlxx` prefix will be altered is having nested master pages for a .aspx page.

Please refer [Control ID Naming in Content Pages (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs) for more information.

Comment: I've been experimenting to see if I can get the `ctlxx` prefix to change for nested master pages. What I have discovered is that for each master page another `ctl00` prefix is added onto *EVERY* control. So my TextBox located in my main master has the ID of `ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_TBMainMaster` when there are 3 master pages. My text box located on my page has the id of `ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_CPMainMaster_CPMaster2_CPMaster3_TextBoxOnPage`. I'm currently not seeing any way of changing the `ctl00` prefix using code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an id created for every nested master page, you might want to test the theory by nesting and then seeing how the Ids look though, as I don't have the tools available where I am right now to provide the proof :/

Comment: I felt bad about not being able to prove it, found this PDF via google, stating the CTLXX constitutes the ID value for the master page. (It's an incremental ID, think that might be enough to prove that nesting would be the only time you will see this ID with a higher value :) ) http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/f/6/8f6349e4-6554-405a-bcd7-9b094ba5089a/ASPNET_MasterPages_Tutorial_05_VB.pdf

Comment: A very interesting article. And it even specifically mentions the ctl00! `While this code will certainly work, it assumes that the master page's autogenerated ID will 
always be ctl00. It's never a good idea to make assumptions about autogenerated values.` but it does not say what would make it render as something else.

Comment: Parag Meshram has copy and pasted the relevant section in the article which states that this is a sequentially increasing integer value. Unless you were enquiring as to an instance whereby the auto-generated id produces something other than ctl00? 

The warning about not making assumptions about auto-generated values is simply because as developers we shouldn't make assumptions and instead create something dynamic that can be deployed anywhere. For instance if you created a web app and referenced the ctl00 page, this would have to be changed if deployed into a site with nested containers.